# How to show interactive matplotlib figure inline in a ipython (jupyter) notebook at a desired place?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython

In an ipython notebook, I have a function that among other things generates a plot. This function is called several times and I would like to collect all these plots (without actually showing them) and then show them in a result summary at the end of my notebook. Also, I really would like to show them as interactive plots inline.

The problem can be shown with the following example. The function I use to demonstrate is defined by this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
%matplotlib notebook

display(HTML("<style>.container { width:90% !important; }</style>"))

def fancy_function(a):
    ret_str = 'Chosen amplitude: {}'.format(a)
    print 'This output is needed for debugging.'

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2.5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    y = a*np.sin(x)
    ax.plot(x, y)

    return (fig, ax, ret_str)
```

Now, I can just do

```
result = [fancy_function(i) for i in xrange(1,3)]
```

and the plots will be shown as interactive plots inline. However, they are just shown where they are created, i.e. I cannot use them in my summary, but instead they are shown mixed with my debug output.

Alternatively, I can do:

```
plt.close()
plt.ioff()
result = [fancy_function(i) for i in xrange(3,5)]
plt.show()
```

The plots are now shown at the end as interactive inline plots, however, they are all shown together. Thus, I cannot add my descriptions to the plots.

To show the plots with my description, I can do:

```
plt.close()
plt.ioff()
result = [fancy_function(i) for i in xrange(3,5)]
plt.ion()
for res in result:
    display(HTML('<h2>{}</h2>'.format(res[2])))
    display(res[0])
```

This will show a nice summary with my plots. However, these plots are not interactive anymore.

Does anyone know how I can show the plots inline at an arbitrary place like in the last case but show them as interactive plots?